# Poetry config resolution order. Do Environment variables superseed poetry config file?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I created a python package with poetry.
I can control poetry's behaviour either with a config file and the config commands
`poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true`
or with environment variable `VIERTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=false`.
If I specify a configuration in both places, which one will be chosen?

Comment: I would say the environment variables take precedence, as is often the case with all such tools, because it seems the most logical. But indeed, it does not seem to be documented.

Comment: Note that it should be `POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=false`. Pay attention to typos and the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `export POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=false` in the `.envrc` with [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) has precedence over `poetry.toml`.